# Conjecture about the irreducibility of special polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

Define $$f(n)=\prod_{j=1}^n (x-j)+\prod_{j=1}^n (x-(j+n))$$

If $n>1$ is odd, then it is easy to show $$(2x-2n-1)\mid f(n)$$

My conjecture is the following :

- For even $n$ , $\frac{f(n)}{2}\in \mathbb Z[x]$
- For even $n$ , $\frac{f(n)}{2}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$
- For odd $n>1$ , $\frac{f(n)}{2x-2n-1}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$

The conjecture is true upto $n=200$. Can we prove it ?

Comment: The first conjecture is clearly true by reducing $f$ mod $n$.

Comment: Yes $\bmod 2$ the first item gives $ n\equiv 0$ and $$f(n)\equiv \prod_{j=1}^n (x-j)+\prod_{j=1}^n (x-j)=2\prod_{j=1}^n (x-j)\equiv 0 \pmod 2.$$ For the irreducibility I suspect there won't be a simple generic way (I've tried a lots of criteria but even for small $n$ there are already examples which do not fit any of them). But we will see.

Comment: There is no linear factorization for $f(n)$ in both odd and even cases, since for any $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ $f(n)[x] \not=0$ which is not hard to prove and since $\mathbb{Z}[x] \subset \mathbb{R}[x]$ it suffice to prove that there is no quadratic factorization for $f(n)$, i would try to solve it using $f(n)[n], f(n)[n+1]$

Comment: The even part holds upto $n=1\ 000$

Comment: The odd part holds upto $n=400$. No idea why, but PARI/GP needs much longer for the verification of the odd cases.